# Google geo coding keeps returning the city centre location for different places

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, geocoding

I am using google auto complete(GMSAutocompletePrediction) to get the attributedFullText(result.attributedFullText.string), the chosen suggestions is used in the following code, which is the geocoding to get the latitude and longitude from the attributedFullText. For many different places the returned origin is the city centre of the city i am looking on.

Knowing that the language used is Arabic

```
if let correctedAddress = self.allAddresses[0][(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].full.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) {
                if let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(correctedAddress)&sensor=false") {
                    print(correctedAddress)
                    print(self.allAddresses[0][(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].full)
                    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                        // 3
                        do {
                            if data != nil{
                                if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:Any],
                                    let results = jsonObject["results"] as? [[String:Any]], !results.isEmpty,
                                    let geometry = results[0]["geometry"] as? [String:Any],
                                    let location = geometry["location"] as? [String:Double],
                                    let lat = location["lat"], let lng = location["lng"] {
                                     print("\(lat) - \(lng)")
                                    let newAddress = Address(name: self.allAddresses[0][(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].name , detail: self.allAddresses[0][(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].detail, latitude: String(lat), longitude: String(lng))
                                    // go back to the previous view controller
                                    self.delegate?.userDidChooseLocation(newAddress)
                                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                                }

                            }

                        }catch {
                            print("Error")
                        }
                    }) 
                    // 5
                    task.resume()
                }
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll be much better of using the Place ID:

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_prediction.html#a1c5f68fbd615425c3dcc5cb60b8b16c7

You can also query the Google Maps Geocoding API web service with the Place ID from Autocomplete:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=(placeId)&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Note that an API key is required for this kind of requests.

Also, the sensor parameter was retired long ago.